# Merge smashing into an existing rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dashing

I'm setting up a dashboard using [smashing](https://smashing.github.io/) however I was wondering if it were possible to integrate it into my existing rails application and keep it all on the same web server rather than having two set up and doing API calls to one another?

I was also wondering if it would be possible for me to access the methods within my rails project from my dashboard?

I attempted to integrate this gem [dashing-rails](https://github.com/gottfrois/dashing-rails)  but can't get it to style or update properly as the smashing dashboard does.

I have methods within ruby that compute the dashboard metrics I need, ideally I would be able to access them but if not I don't mind making API calls. I would like to have my existing rails application and dashboard on the same server.

Comment: You might be better off picking up a template from bootstrap gallery and setting it up in your rails app.

Comment: Could you mount it as an engine within your Rails app?